# Run A multiplatform xcode project

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, cocoa, ios6

I have a project that has two targets one for iOS and other OSX. When I run the project it builds successfully. But Its nit running.I want to run this ample project in any of the platform. How can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work, because iOS and OS X are based on different frameworks.iOS needs UIKit. But if you compile a project for Mac that contains UIKit, you will get an error. You cant just set Xcode to compile for Mac if you use the wrong 'base classes'.

Just create 2 Xcode projects that contain all the classes you want to use, one for OS X, one for iOS.